# Retrieving data from LDAP

Tags: java, ldap

I want to fetch data from LDAP server. I can retrieve all users from the list. But now, what I want to do is get the person list under 'directReports' attribute. It returns users as java Objects. I cannot convert them to any type other than toString(). What I have done is convert objects to String and use string operations to get users' names. But I think this is not a proper way to do this. Please give me a suggestion. Thanks!

````
        @Override
        public Object mapFromAttributes(Attributes attributes) throws NamingException {
            List<LdapUserDetail> ldapUserDetails = new ArrayList<>();
            Attribute directReports = attributes.get("directReports");

            NamingEnumeration ne = directReports.getAll();
            while(ne.hasMore()){
                try {
                    Object item = ne.next();
                    String emp = item.toString();
                    emp = Arrays.stream(emp.split(",")).filter(name -> name.startsWith("CN")).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0).split("CN")[1];
                    LdapUserDetail ldapUserDetail = new LdapUserDetail();
                    ldapUserDetail.setName(emp);;
                    ldapUserDetails.add(ldapUserDetail);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            logger.info("checklist "+ldapUserDetails.size());
            return ldapUserDetails;
        }
    } ```
````

Comment: Use your debugger, or simple print `item.getClass()` to see what type they actually are.

Comment: @tgdavies  It's String type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LDAP, the `directReports` attribute (==field) is of *Distinguished Name (DN)* type. That is a pointer to another object in the database, in this case a user. When you read it in Java, you get a list of strings.

Typically, the DN is of the format `CN=username,OU=department,O=organization`.
CN may also be UID in some implementations. If the CN is what you want, then simply parsing the DN string value with two `split()` commands will work:

```
// We take off at your line
String emp = item.toString();
String[] dnParts = emp.split(",");
String cnValue = dnParts[0].split("=")[1];
```

It is wise to do some sanity checking for `null` values in between.

If you want to retrieve other details about the user that the DN value is pointing to, you will need to read that object from LDAP in a second operation (LDAP reads are very fast):

```
// We take off at your line
String emp = item.toString();
// Create controls for the LDAP operation
SearchControls ctrl = new SearchControls();
// Tell LDAP this is a read
ctrl.setSearchScope(SearchControls.OBJECT_SCOPE);
// Request all attributes for this object
ctrl.setReturningAttributes(new String[] {"*", "+"});
// I assume you have an LdapContext object called ctx
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = ctx.search(emp, "objectclass=*", controls);
while (results.hasMore())
{
    // This is your user object with all its attributes
    SearchResult result = results.next(); 
    // Always close the enumeration to prevent memory leaks
    results.close();
    break;
}
```